# Bounds on a partition theorem with ambivalent colors

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I've been running into the following type of partition problem.

> Given positive integers *h*, *r*, *k*, and a real number ε ∈ (0,1), find *n* such that if every (unordered) *r*-tuple from an *n* element set *X* is assigned a set of at least ε*k* 'valid' colors out of a total of *k* possible colors, then you can find *H* ⊆ *X* of size *h* and a single color which is 'valid' for all *r*-tuples from *H*.

Lower bounds on the smallest such *n* can be obtained from lower bounds for Ramsey's Theorem. If *k* is sufficiently large, then partition the set of colors into [1/ε] pairwise disjoint sets of approximately equal size to emulate a proper [1/ε]-coloring of *r*-tuples. A simple pigeonhole argument shows that this is essentially sharp when *r* = 1 and *k* is large enough, i.e. one color must be 'valid' for at least *n*ε points.

Is the Ramsey bound more or less sharp for *r* > 1 or are there better lower bounds? The interesting case is when *k* is large since the proposed Ramsey lower bound is (surprisingly?) independent of *k*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think that the lower bound could depend only on epsilon. Below is the sketch of my argument.

Fix h=3, r=2, eps=1/4, thus we color the edges of a graph, each with 25% of all the colors and we are looking for a "monochromatic" triangle. Let us take k random bipartitions of the vertices and color the corresponding edges of the bipartite graph with one color. Using [Hoeffding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) or some similar inequality we get that for big enough k every edge is colored at least k/4 times if n is at most exp(ck), where c is some fixed constant with some positive probability. Therefore the bound must depend on k and not only on epsilon.

Comment: Very nice! After coffee, I got the explicit lower bound $n > \sqrt{2}\exp(3k/40)$ when $h=3$ and $\epsilon=1/4$, by using Bernstein's Inequality instead.

Comment: After more coffee, I successfully generalized your trick to arbitrary h, r; I will post the details separately. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generalization of domotorp's answer to arbitrary *h* > *r* > 1.

Independently for each color *i* ∈ {1,2,...,k}, pick a random *H*<sub>*i*</sub> from a family **H** of *r*-hypergraphs that don't contain any complete *r*-hypergraph of size *h*. Declare color *i* to be 'valid' for the *r*-tuple *t* = {*t*<sub>1</sub>,...,*t*<sub>*r*</sub>} iff *t* ∈ *H*<sub>*i*</sub>. Let *Y*<sub>*t*</sub> be the number of 'valid' colors for *t*. Note that *Y*<sub>*t*</sub> is binomial with parameters (*k*, p) for some 0 < p ≤ 1/2 which is independent of *k* and also independent of *t* when **H** is closed under isomorphism. Hoeffding's Inequality then gives

Prob[*Y*<sub>*t*</sub> ≤ εk] ≤ exp(-2k(p-ε)<sup>2</sup>)

for 0 < ε < p. So the probability that *Y*<sub>*t*</sub> ≥ ε*k* for all *i* is positive whenever *n* ≤ exp(2k(p-ε)<sup>2</sup>/r) (not optimal).

This is not enough since p implicitly depends on *n*. However, for fixed *h* > *r* > 1, p can be bounded away from 0. This can be seen by using for **H** the family of *r*-partite hypergraphs as domotorp did, but different choices of **H** give better bounds.

Comment: This answer is community wiki because domtorp deserves all the credit.